# Split a collection in two starting with a certain value

Tags: oracle, parsing, plsql, collections

I have a collection A (table of VARCAHR2) and I want to move the content in two others, B and C (tables of VARCHAR2), if a certain line from A starts with a certain value.

For this I have this part of code:

```
...
        for k in 1 .. v_message.count loop

            if substr(v_message(k), 1, 3) = 'AAA' 
                then
                    l_poz := k;
                    dbms_output.put_line('the position there AAA start is at line (' || l_poz || ')');
                    exit;
            end if;
        end loop;

        for k in 1 .. v_message.count loop

            if k < l_poz 
                then 
                    h := h + 1;
                    v_header.extend(1);
                    v_header(h)  := v_message(k);
                    dbms_output.put_line('v_header(' || h || ') = ' || v_header(h));

                else
                    l := l + 1;
                    v_lines.extend(1);
                    v_lines(l)  := v_message(k);
                    dbms_output.put_line('v_lines(' || l || ') = ' || v_lines(l));
            end if;
        end loop;
...
```

v_message is collection A.

v_header is collection B.

v_lines is collection C.

A test message should look like:

> ABX*xxx#dddd
>
> ADF*xxx#dddd
>
> SFM*xxx#ffff
>
> AAA*xxx#mmmm
>
> ABX*yyy#rrrr
>
> MMM*jjj#llll
>
> ATM*jjj#rrrr
>
> SFM*xxx#tttt

and I want to split this message in:

> ABX*xxx#dddd
>
> ADF*xxx#dddd
>
> SFM*xxx#ffff

and

> AAA*xxx#mmmm
>
> ABX*yyy#rrrr
>
> MMM*jjj#llll
>
> ATM*jjj#rrrr
>
> SFM*xxx#tttt

My code is working fine but I am wondering if this split can be done in a single parse of collection A.

Is it possible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in one loop, declare some variable (`v_coll`) and do something like here:

```
    v_coll := 'B';

    for k in 1 .. v_message.count loop

        if v_coll = 'B' and substr(v_message(k), 1, 3) = 'AAA' then 
          v_coll := 'C';
        end;

        if v_coll = 'B'
            then 
              -- insert into headers
            else
              -- insert into lines
        end if;
    end loop;
```

Comment: wouldn't your example insert in B only the line where 'AAA' exists, and put all the rest in C?!

Comment: I didn't test it, but it insert into `B` until it finds `AAA`. From this moment it inserts into `C`.